# pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN registers several clicks when used outside main function

Tags: python, pygame

Have a look at the code:

```
import pygame 
import sys

def check(screen, event):
    pos = 0
    pos = positionNow(event)

def positionNow(event):
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        val = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        print(val)

def main():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 600))

    running = True
    while running:  

        events = pygame.event.get()
        for event in events:
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

        check(screen, event)
        pygame.display.update()

main()
```

Example output:

```
(333, 268)
(333, 268)
(333, 268)
(333, 268)
(333, 268)
(333, 268)
(333, 268)
(333, 268)
(333, 268)
(333, 268)
(333, 268)
(333, 268)
(333, 268)
(333, 268)
(333, 268)
(333, 268)
(333, 268)
(333, 268)
(333, 268)
(333, 268)
(333, 268)
(333, 268)
(333, 268)
(333, 268)
(333, 268)
(333, 268)
(333, 268)
(333, 268)
(333, 268)
(333, 268)
(333, 268)
(333, 268)
(333, 268)
(333, 268)
(333, 268)
(333, 268)
(333, 268)
(333, 268)
(333, 268)
(333, 268)
(333, 268)
(333, 268)
(333, 268)
(333, 268)
(333, 268)
(333, 268)
(333, 268)
(333, 268)
(333, 268)
(333, 268)
(333, 268)
(333, 268)
(333, 268)
(333, 268)
(333, 268)
(333, 268)
(333, 268)
(333, 268)
(333, 268)
(333, 268)
(333, 268)
(333, 268)
(333, 268)
(333, 268)
(333, 268)
(333, 268)
```

I am using `pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` method to get the coordinates of the mouse when any mouse button is clicked. Problem is when I make `pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` as a separate function outside the WHILE loop inside the main function it prints out the `val` (coordinates of the mouse when button clicked) several times. I want to print it just once as `pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` is supposed to.

Now I could have everything under `main()`'s while loop and get it working as shown below. But my objective is to get this done as a separate function.

```
import pygame 
import sys

def main():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 600))

    running = True
    while running:  

        events = pygame.event.get()
        for event in events:
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                val = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                print(val)

        pygame.display.update()

main()
```

Example output:

```
(389, 86)
```

Why is this happening exactly and how do I overcome it?

Comment: The indentation on `check(screen, event)` is not inside the `for event in events:` loop.  So it's being called every *frame* not for every *event*.  So when the last-most event was MOUSE-DOWN, all your check-conditions still hold.  If you're moving the mouse (or suchlike) these new events will stop this continuous-loop, making it seem like it's only a couple of loops.

Comment: It's a matter of [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html). You've to invoke `check` in the event loop rather than the main application loop.

Comment: @Kingsley Oh now I see! It works perfectly, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a matter of [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html). You must invoke `check` **in** the event loop rather than the after the **event** loop:

```py
def main():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 600))

    running = True
    while running:  

        events = pygame.event.get()
        for event in events:
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

            # INDENTATION

        #-->|
            check(screen, event)
        
        pygame.display.update()

main()
```